# Obtener nuevos registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Buenas tardes quisiera saber como puedo obtener cuantos registros han sido insertados recientemente lo que necesito es contar cuantos productos son nuevos por ejemplo en esta consulta el primer registro es nuevo ya que el resto si fueron ingresados con anterioridad

```
select DISTINCT pcl.IdCliente, PCL.IdProducto,pcl.FechaImp
from dbCRM.dbo.ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO ase with(nolock),
dbCRM.dbo.PRODUCTO_CLIENTE pcl with(nolock)
where
ase.IdCliente=pcl.IdCliente
and ase.IdAsesor=5
--and pcl.FechaImp=@Fecha
and ase.Habilitado=1;
```

[image: Consulta]

Comment: No es claro el criterio para "nuevo producto"

Comment: Osea que no exista ese producto con una fecha anterior asignado al cliente

Comment: En otras palabras, ¿nuevo es cuando es la primera vez que se asigna a un cliente, a partir de cierta fecha que nos interese? o, ¿cuándo es "nuevo"?

Comment: Si nuevo seria la primera vez que se le asigna a ese cliente, necesito contabilizar el numero de productos nuevos en una fecha determinada en el ejemplo que puse la respuesta deberia ser 1

Answer (score 0):

En base a lo que mencionas en los comentarios podrías usar una condición en el `WHERE`, especificando que los datos sean igual o mayor a la fecha ingresada por el usuario, por ejemplo:

```
declare @fecha as date = '2019-04-23';
select DISTINCT pcl.IdCliente, PCL.IdProducto,pcl.FechaImp
from dbCRM.dbo.ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO ase with(nolock),
dbCRM.dbo.PRODUCTO_CLIENTE pcl with(nolock)
where
ase.IdCliente=pcl.IdCliente
and ase.IdAsesor=5
and pcl.FechaImp>=@Fecha
and ase.Habilitado=1;
```

En este ejemplo se devuelven todos los registros mayores o iguales a la fecha `2019-04-23`.

Observé que tenías comentado una variable `@fecha`, por lo que declaré una variable para hacer el ejemplo, si no deseas utilizarla sería cuestión de colocar el valor de la fecha directamente después del operador `>=`. Si existe algún detalle hazlo saber para modificar la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr el resultado utilizando CTE's, te explico la idea:

- Primero declaro dos CTE's llamados `ASIGANCION_SEGMENTO` y `PRODUCTO_CLIENTE` con el fin de simular tus tablas originales, estos puedes ignorarlos
- En el CTE `CalculoNumeroAsignacion` incluyo la información de la tabla `PRODUCTO_CLIENTE` y agrego una nueva columna llamada `NumeroAsignacionProductoCliente`, donde utilizo la función `row_number()` para numerar las asignaciones de producto que se han hecho a cada cliente de manera cronológica.
- en el CTE `NuevasAsignaciones` filtro el resultado anterior, conservando solamente aquellas filas que tengan número 1, pues esos son los *productos nuevos*, según la definición que has dado en comentarios de tu pregunta.
- Finalmente, hago la consulta, que es muy similar a la de tu pregunta, pero en lugar de utilizar directamente la tabla `PRODUCTO_CLIENTE`, utilizo la *vista* `NuevasAsignaciones`, que como ya dijimos, tiene solamente los *nuevos productos*.

En código, luce así:

```
with
ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO as (
select 5 idAsesor, 8 idCliente
union all select 5, 31
union all select 5, 33
union all select 1, 99
)
,
PRODUCTO_CLIENTE as (
select 8 idCliente, 13 idProducto, cast('20190423' as date) FechaImp
union all select 31, 13, '20190410'
union all select 31, 13, '20190423'
union all select 31, 22, '20190410'
union all select 31, 22, '20190423'
union all select 33, 22, '20190410'
union all select 33, 22, '20190423'
union all select 99, 22, '20190410'
union all select 99, 22, '20190423'
)
,
CalculoNumeroAsignacion as (
select   idCliente
       , idProducto
       , FechaImp
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by idCliente, idProducto order by FechaImp) NumeroAsignacionProductoCliente
  from PRODUCTO_CLIENTE
)
,
NuevasAsignaciones as (
select *
  from CalculoNumeroAsignacion
 where NumeroAsignacionProductoCliente = 1
)
select   pcl.idCliente
       , pcl.idProducto
       , pcl.FechaImp
  from NuevasAsignaciones pcl
       inner join ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO ase on ase.idCliente = pcl.idCliente
 where ase.idAsesor = 5
   and pcl.FechaImp = '20190423';
```

Con los datos de muestra, el resultado que produce es este:

```
idCliente   idProducto  FechaImp
----------- ----------- ----------
8           13          2019-04-23

(1 row affected)
```